# Javascript не работает

Tags: javascript, ajax

```js
var cities = {
  bra: ["Сан-Паулу", "Рио-де-Жанейро"],
  rus: ["Москва", "Санкт-Петербург"],
  ind: ["Мумбаи", "Дели"],
  chn: ["Шанхай", "Пекин"],
  zaf: ["Йоханнесбург", "Кейптаун"]
};
var country = document.getElementById("country");
var city = document.querySelector("#city");
window.onload = selectCountry;
country.onchange = selectCountry;

function selectCountry(ev) {
  city.innerHTML = "";
  var c = this.value || "bra",
    o;
  for (let i = 0; i < cities[c].length; i++) {
    o = new Option(cities[c][i], i, false, false);
    city.add(o);
  };
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

h2 {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  font-family: Times New Roman;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<select name="country" id="country">
  <option value="bra" selected>Бразилия</option>
  <option value="rus">Россия</option>
  <option value="ind">Индия</option>
  <option value="chn">Китай</option>
  <option value="zaf">ЮАР</option>
</select>
<select name="city" id="city">
</select>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: и что ту не работает?

Comment: Не инициализируется переменная country. Похоже код выполняется раньше, чем загружается страница. Какие атрибуты заданы у тэга <script>? Где прописан код?

Comment: Скрипт раньше разметки выводится?